# Create a 3D array from a list

Tags: php

I have the following list:

> 1945/01/05    BA  87  34  1   59  50
>   1945/01/05    CA  18  17  45  49  82
>   1945/01/13    BA  6   66  1   16  48
>   1945/01/13    CA  40  60  32  50  80

and so on....

I want to arrange them as an array like the following:

```
$array['BA'][0][0] = 87;
$array['BA'][0][1] = 34;
$array['BA'][0][2] = 1;
$array['BA'][0][3] = 59;
$array['BA'][0][4] = 50;

$array['CA'][0][0] = 18;
$array['CA'][0][1] = 17;
$array['CA'][0][2] = 45;
$array['CA'][0][3] = 49;
$array['CA'][0][4] = 82;

$array['BA'][1][0] = 6;
$array['BA'][1][1] = 66;
$array['BA'][1][2] = 1;
$array['BA'][1][3] = 16;
$array['BA'][1][4] = 48;

$array['CA'][1][0] = 48;
$array['CA'][1][1] = 60;
$array['CA'][1][2] = 32;
$array['CA'][1][3] = 50;
$array['CA'][1][4] = 80;
```

I know that I can use preg_split('/\s+/', $list); to create an array, but how can I create a 3D Array from this list?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

Updated the code so you can also load a file since you have memory issues.
Consider: If loading the amount of data already creates memory issues your end result, the array, might also generate memory issues! Since that's even more data!

So this will read per line so it does not load the total file in memory directly. But since you have memory issues you should likely not write to an array but to a database for example. Otherwise the memory issue will keep coming.

```
<?PHP

/*
 * Example when small amount of data is in a string
 */

/*
//your input
$str='1945/01/05 BA 87 34 1 59 50
1945/01/05 CA 18 17 45 49 82
1945/01/13 BA 6 66 1 16 48
1945/01/13 CA 40 60 32 50 80';

//we work per line
$lines=explode("\n", $str);

//loop each line
foreach($lines AS $line) {

*/

/*
 * Example when big amount of data is in a file
 */
//this will contain the end result
$result=array();

$filename='lines.txt'; //contains the data like in your question

$fp = fopen($filename,'r');
while($line=fgets($fp)) {
    //explode each line on space so we get the different fields
    $fields=explode(' ', $line);

    //we remove the date, not needed
    unset($fields[0]);

    //we get the key (BA/CA/etc) and remove it also
    $key=$fields[1];
    unset($fields[1]);

    //we write the result to the array
    //using array_values so the indexes are from 0-4 again
    //because we removed items
    $result[$key][]=array_values($fields);

}


fclose($fp);

//show the result in html
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

THE QUESTION CHANGED

This does answer the question asked in the comments, not the actual question.

```
<?PHP

/*
 * Example when big amount of data is in a file
 */
//this will contain the end result
$result=array();

$filename='lines.txt'; //contains the data like in your question

$fp = fopen($filename,'r');
while($line=fgets($fp)) {
    //explode each line on space so we get the different fields
    $fields=explode(' ', $line);

    //we remove the date, not needed
    unset($fields[0]);

    //we get the key (BA/CA/etc) and remove it also
    $key=$fields[1];
    unset($fields[1]);

    //We start counting the numbers
    foreach($fields AS $nr) {
        $nr=trim($nr);
        if(empty($result[$key][$nr])) {
            $result[$key][$nr]=1;
        }else{
            $result[$key][$nr]++;
        }
    }

}


fclose($fp);

//show the result in html
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in file.php on line $fields=explode(' ', $line).

Comment: It works replacing that line with $fields=preg_split('/\s+/', $line) but now arrays have 1 more index (5 instead of 4). Why?

Comment: How big is your file? That was not supplied in question. If it's very big you need a different approach by reading per line instead of a gigantic file at one in memory.

Comment: Added a new version which also allows to load from a file (check security when loading files!). Since you already have a memory limit of 128 MB I expect your file is too big. Maybe you should ask another question or expand this one about how to handle big amounts of data. Loading all in memory is most of the time not the right solution.

Comment: preg_split works well, the only problem is that arrays have 1 blank array

Comment: What do you do with the array after creating it? What's the use of such a big array with all this data? Maybe if we know that we can find a smarter less memory expensive solution.

Comment: I want to find the most common numbers in in each group (BA, CA, etc.) and display them along with number of times.

Comment: I see for example 2 times the number 1 in BA. I read your example data. Do you mean that it could be possible that BA contains for example 5 time nr 87? If yes, is the position of the number relevant? So whether it is the first or the last number in a row, does it matter?

Comment: No it's not relevant. I only want a descending list of numbers. Example: 18 = 5 times, 27 = 10 times, 84 = 1 time, etc.

Comment: The new update does what you want, you have to sort the results ascending, it is best to do that when you are showing it or loop them again but that will save time.

Comment: Thank you very much. However it works on xampp, but when I upload it on the server it returns a blank page. Maybe it's a memory problem?

Comment: Turn on all error logging and showing E_ALL, display errors etcetera so you see what goes wrong. Debugging a white page is impossible, first make sure you see what goes wrong. If that does not work add something like: echo $nr."\n";flush(); so you can see what happens. Normally a production server has settings to hide errors and have more strict limits on memory, execution time, max time for a page load etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = '1945/01/05 BA 87 34 1 59 50
1945/01/05 CA 18 17 45 49 82
1945/01/13 BA 6 66 1 16 48
1945/01/13 CA 40 60 32 50 80';

$array = array();
$list = explode("\n", $a);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($list);
echo '</pre>';
$first_index = 0;
$counter = 0;
foreach($list as $key=>$value) {
    if($counter >=2) {
        $first_index++;
        $counter= 0;
    }
    $row = explode(" ",$value);
    $k = $row[1];

    for($i=2; $i< count($row); $i++) {      
        $array[$k][$first_index][] = $row[$i];          
    }
    $counter++;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Had the same issue as you have in your code, the keys of the deepest arrays are not 0-4 but in your case 0,2,4,6,8. See the array_values in my post.

Comment: yes now your indexes are correct. As you see in my example it is not required to do lots of things with the counters and indexes since it will be ordered automatically by the PHP arrays. So it will save lots of code and counters which add complexity and increase chances for bugs. But yes the code is now working and outputting what it should do according to the question.